# .net core 2.1 Test Result not displaying in TFS 2018

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, test-results

I have .net core 2.1 project build pipeline as shown below.

[image]

I have 2 simple unit test cases which executed successfully. “.NET Core test” command executes successfully and publishes thereport.

```
2018-09-06T22:05:41.8494077Z 
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0138714Z Passed   Login_Test
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0139277Z Passed   Logoff_Test
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0495295Z Results File: P:\*******2018-09-06_17_05_41.trx
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0514262Z 
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0516990Z Attachments:
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0517972Z   P:\*****\TestResults\329a8629-7ec1-454b-97d8-2623d29bbd0e\XXXXX 2018-09-06 17_05_39.coverage
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0518130Z 
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0518516Z Total tests: 2. Passed: 2. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0519312Z Test Run Successful.
2018-09-06T22:05:42.0528123Z Test execution time: 1.9003 Seconds
2018-09-06T22:05:42.1424722Z Publishing test results to test run '90'
2018-09-06T22:05:42.1424881Z Test results remaining: 2. Test run id: 90
2018-09-06T22:05:42.1592889Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2018-09-06T22:05:42.2384075Z Published Test Run : http://******/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=90&_a=runCharts
2018-09-06T22:05:42.2384433Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2018-09-06T22:05:42.2385471Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies
```

But I don’t see any “Test Results” under dashboard.
 [image]

I included "Visual Studio Test" too, but still dont see the result in the dashboard. What am I missing here?

Comment: The photos are too small, can you fix it?

Comment: What's the result if you access that test run URL? (http://******/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=90&_a=runCharts)  Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail log here.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, i can see the test result with nice chart. unfortunately due to security reasons i can't share  log details.

Comment: So, just the test result isn't displayed in build summary? Can you reproduce this issue with a simple sample? If so, can you share this sample project on the OneDrive?